# How to ensure the Golang channel waits for the data and the program does not terminate if Stdin does not have data

Tags: go

I have a Golang program which makes real time predictions on a machine learning model built using TensorFlow. The data for the prediction needs to be read line by line from Stdin and the prediction has to be performed on each line of data. The flow of data is not constant. I need a system that ensures that every time there is data to be read from Stdin, the prediction method is invoked and if there is no data in Stdin, the program waits for new data and does not terminate.

I tried achieving this using channels and the select, but if there is no data in the Stdin, the program terminates. Below is the code snippet:

```
  func run_the_model(in <-chan string) {
     go func(){
        ...  
        ...  
        ...
         //Fetch the model
         //Run the prediction 
         //print the result on StdOut
     }() 
  }

  func main() {
   data := make(chan string)
   // read data from Stdin
   go func() {
       scan := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
       for scan.Scan() {
           data <- scan.Text()
       }

   }()
   time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)

   select{
      case <-data:
        run_the_model(data)
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
      default:
        println("Waiting for data")
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(math.MaxInt64))
   }
  }
```

When there is no new data in Stdin the Select's default case must be executed and when there is new data in the `data` channel, the `run_the_model` must be executed. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to loop and execute your `select` many times instead of just once?

Comment: That said, try to avoid the resulting "polling" style in go - if you want to do two things, run them in separate goroutines and use channels as /coordination points/.

Comment: Let's say I have x number of lines of data in Stdin and I am expecting more y number of lines of data after z milliseconds, the prediction is performed for the x number of lines  but after that it terminates the program. I am expecting it to wait until it encounters the y number of lines instead of terminating. Could you please elaborate how would looping the select statement be the solution for it? Note: There is no fixed value for x, y z

Comment: As is, the first time it hits the select - maybe even before there is any input available on the scanner - it will go through the default, sleep, and then exit `main()` No?  You want to wait for /input/.  The thing about "not polling" means you should try not to use `default`, in this use case.  Certainly if you don't want it to immediately exit, or exit after one input - you'll need a loop.   You want to process /multiple/ input lines, as you say.

Comment: (Another way to put the higher-level suggestion about how to use channels:  prefer to think of them as "pipelines in a factory" rather than "I/O multiplexors"...)

Comment: You can remove the `time.Sleep` call and place your `select` statement in a `for` loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your `select` in infinite loop.

```
for {
   select{
      case <-data:
        run_the_model(data)
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
      default:
        println("Waiting for data")
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(math.MaxInt64))
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think u using select wrong , for your case this should be works:

```
func runTheModel(in string) {
    // do what ever u want
}

func main() {
    data := make(chan string)
    // read data from Stdin
    go func() {
        scan := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
        for scan.Scan() {
            data <- scan.Text()
        }

    }()
    println("waiting for data:")
    for d := range data {
        // command to exit program
        if d == "q" {
            return
        }
        go runTheModel(d)
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the data flow is not constant, I want my program to wait when there is no data and constantly print `Waiting for data` and when there would be data in Stdin, I want the model to be run. As per my understanding, this can be achieved using channels and select, where if there is no data in any channels the default case is run and if there is data in the channel the `run_the_model` method is called.

Comment: It's waiting in loop tile close channel or break the loop, just test it dude